# Activity is not visible when using shared element transition

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, shared-element-transition

I'm trying to move from list activity to details activity using shared element transition
but when using shared element the target activity is not visible

when i don't use shared element it works normally

[image: app without shared element transition]

but when i use shared element transition activity is not visible like below

[image: app with shared element transition]

I have tried setting details activity background to white but it's not working

this is how i start activity

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, NewsActivity.class);
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putParcelable(Constants.NEWS, news);
            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, view, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(view));
            intent.putExtra(DATA, data);
            startActivity(intent,options.toBundle());
```

my details activity xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".ui.news.NewsActivity"
app:layoutDescription="@xml/collapsing_toolbar_news">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:srcCompat="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:transitionName="news"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/news_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:paddingTop="24dp"
    android:paddingStart="24dp"
    android:paddingEnd="24dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/news_title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:paddingStart="24dp"
    android:paddingEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_news">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/kanit_regular"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_text"
            android:text="@string/large_text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

my recycler item xml

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:strokeColor="#BDBDBD"
    app:strokeWidth="1dp">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.islam.custom.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/news_image"
            android:transitionName="news"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_questions_background"
            app:riv_corner_radius="10dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_gradient_20"/>
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            style="@style/progressbar"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:fontFamily="@font/kanit_regular"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: What I first saw is that both images don't have the same types.

Comment: After i saw your comment i tried to change the custom RoundedImageView to ImageView and the same behavior happen activity still not visible

Answer (score 0):

After searching i found that the problem was because i used launchmode for root activity

```
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

but i don't know how this made it not working properly .
and i still need to set the launchmode for the root activity

Comment: Interestingly, this 'behaviour' exists before 29, but works fine at 29 & 30